# Navigation Based Template? Iphone app like Facebook App

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

Im creating my first iphone app and need some advice. Im basically developing a simple social app similar to the facebook iphone app.

Should I start with the Navigation Template? Or am i totally on the wrong path?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Mock up how you want it to look, visualize things from your users perspective. That will dictate how you are going to approach things. Once you have that figured out in a way that's satisfactory, you're going to be looking at one of a few possibilities: Navigation based, tab based, or building a custom view.

Comment: Ive done a basic mock up. It will have a login screen for the user to login, on login it will go to a simple listing of comments. The user can click a menu button in the top bar and it will take them to the central menu with will be formatted like facebooks central menu so on icon click in the central menu it will transition to the new view.

Comment: Then it sounds like you're going to want to create custom views, and transition between your login screen and your main screen -- as well as between the main screen and the respective views each of those icons represents afterwards. You can avoid writing some of this code by looking at the Three20 framework, but I really recommend against Three20. It has some major design flaws that you'd be well advised to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

[three20](http://github.com/blog/389-three20-iphone-ui-goodness)